# How do you test the Cmd of an update function?

Tags: unit-testing, elm

I want to write a test that says, "If `update` is called with a `GetData` msg, it returns a `(_, httpCmd)`.  I'm not sure how to write this test.  I know how to get the response as a `(model, cmd)`, but I don't know how to parse the `cmd` to see what's inside it.

How do people test the `Cmd` response of their `update` function?

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, `Cmd`s are opaque - you can't see inside them.

There is [`elm-testable`](https://github.com/avh4/elm-testable) which you could use, but it needs some preparation from your side.

There is also [a rewrite](https://github.com/avh4/elm-testable/tree/rewrite-native) underway, that will, when done, allow you to keep your original code and test that directly.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to look at it so that I can justify not being able to test the Cmd?  In my mind, it's pretty risky.